# Python: Why is binary AND operator allowed between sets, but not lists?

Tags: python, set, operators

Why can I do `set('dog') & set('hotdog')` to find the similar letters, but cannot do the same with a list? i.e `['dog'] & ['hotdog']`

What is the reasoning for this from a computer science perspective?

Comment: Because `list`s aren't sets in the formal definition.

Comment: First, there's no well-defined ordering behavior for performing such an operation. Second, performance would necessarily be comparatively poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `list` is allowed to have duplicates, so they cannot be treated as a `set`. There is no formal definition of what intersection, difference, etc would mean if the elements are not unique.

For example, what would the difference of this be

```
'aaabbc' - 'aab'
```

Should you remove them only up to the counts of each unique element?

```
'abc'
```

Or remove any element that occurs in the second list?

```
'c'
```